# Amy's grandmother gave her 3 identical chocolate chip cookies and 4 identical sugar cookies.

Tags: combinatorics

Amy's grandmother gave her 3 identical chocolate chip cookies and 4 identical sugar cookies. In how many different orders can Amy eat the cookies such that either she eats a chocolate chip cookie first, she eats a chocolate chip cookie last, or both?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the user created an account with a vulgar name and spewed profanity in the form of an answer. This account should be blocked immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: count the total number of orders, then subtract the number that start and end with sugar cookies.